# Es posible enviar parametros?

Tags: javascript

Es posible enviar parametros a una función anónima desde otra función?

Teniendo:

```
function noSabe(){ return 'nosé como enviartelos';}


(function(a,b){

// Necesito recibir parametros

})();
```

Comment: Sí, se puede enviar parámetros a una función anónima, y mucho más sencillo de hacer con una [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)... El tema es ¿cómo pensabas **llamar** a una función **anónima** desde otra función?

Comment: Por eso pregunto Mariano..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He aquí algunas formas de pasar variables a funciones anónimas

```js
var variableA = "Hola ";
var variableB = "Mundo";

//Funcion anonima asignada a una variable
var funcionAnonima = function(a,b){console.log("funcionAnonima: " + a+b);}

//Ejecutamos funcion anonima pasandole dos variables
funcionAnonima(variableA, variableB);

//Funcion anonima IIFE
(function(a,b){
               console.log("Funcion anonima IIFE: " + a+b);
 })(variableA, variableB); //Pasamos las variables aqui
```